# How to release a beta version of ios application without app store

Tags: ios

I created an ios application and want to release it for a particular group of users. I don't want to get their device ID and generate a AdHoc release. Is there a way for me to release this kind of version without go through apple store?

I have read this link: https://developer.apple.com/programs/enterprise/enroll/  .  It says: "Enroll in the Apple Developer Enterprise Program only if you intend to distribute proprietary apps to employees within your organization." But  I don't understand what it means by "within organization".

Comment: Are you talking about Enterprise Program? https://developer.apple.com/programs/enterprise/

Comment: Does enterprise distribution have any limitation on end users? I have read this link: https://developer.apple.com/programs/enterprise/enroll/  .  It says: "Enroll in the Apple Developer Enterprise Program only if you intend to distribute proprietary apps to employees within your organization." But  I don't understand what it means by "within organization".

Comment: It doesn't have any limitation for users count. Organization means you need to be not just individual developer but to represent some real legal organization.

Comment: Yeah the DUNS number isn't a joke, was a mission to get it. How many people are you targeting? You have to have their Device ID to add to the provisioning profile. You can even sync the .app in iTunes with another phone and it will still not work. And I think a while back the limit was 2000 but don't see any limits anymore.

Comment: It sounds like TestFlight would work for you. You need to submit your app for review but it is much less stringent than full App Store review and then all you need is an email address for your beta users

Comment: @apptality The number of people I want to target is more than 1000. And I don't have opportunity to get all of their device ID. So I am looking for some better solution. Thanks for advice

Comment: @Paulw11 Do I need to get their device ID? Is there any limitation on the number of users using it?

Comment: You don't need their device Id. They get sent an email with the download link; they need to install the TestFlight app from the App Store and then the app will be installed. There is a limit of 2000 external testers; https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/BetaTestingTheApp.html